# Flags average handling time ignores seconds, but shows seconds

Tags: bug, status-completed, moderator-tools, statistics, wording

The moderator tools shows something like:

[image: 1.1k flags, average handling time 0 days 0 hours 15 minutes 0 seconds]

(This is the current monthly stats on [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com))

However, I have yet to see the "seconds" value showing anything else than "0 seconds", which indicates that the system doesn't take the seconds into account.

I believe it is misleading to always show 0 seconds when the system doesn't seem to calculate the average handling time including seconds.

I suggest to either start to calculate the average handling time *with* seconds included, or simply drop the "0 seconds" text completely.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I agree, it's weird to always show **0 seconds**.

[Anna](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/155160/anna-lear) completed this last week and got rolled into a build over the weekend.

Enjoy the lack of zero seconds from now on.

Comment: I would rather have seen the seconds actually being used, but oh well, thanks!

Comment: SE mods: 1 Zero: 0