# Are there some public statistics on how long it takes to process flags on each SE site?

Tags: support, flags, statistics

Are there some public statistics on how long it takes to process flags on each SE site?

Comment: My guess would be that it varies per type of flag, with comment flags handled rather easily, and plagiarism or custom voting ring flags taking 6-8 days/weeks.

Answer (score 10):

There are no public statistics; posts like [2021: a year in moderation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/375072/295232) contain related statistics but not flag handling time. Shog9 posted a graph once: [How long does it take on average for moderator flags to be handled here on Meta Stack Exchange?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/315385/295232) but that was just for a single site.

♦ moderators can see it on their dashboard ([example](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/260817/flags-average-handling-time-ignores-seconds-but-shows-seconds)), but that probably only includes flags that can be handled by moderators from the dashboard, so it does not include close flags. I know many sites where the moderators prefer to leave VLQ/NAA flags alone (unless they're obvious) and let the community handle them via the Low Quality Posts review queue, which increases handling time. A site that sees a lot of obvious spam, and relatively few other flags, will likely have a low average handling time thanks to [SmokeDetector and friends](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/291301/295232). So all in all, I think those statistics aren't that useful. Maybe if you'd break them down by flag type?

Comment: Thanks, yes definitely, it'd be more insightful if broken down by flag type.